# Who's the blue alien from The Resistance?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, character-identification, the-resistance

While watching *The Force Awakens*, after the Resistance soldiers came into the battle (I remember Nien Nunb was amongst them), I noticed a blue alien commanding the Resistance's troops.

He kind of looked like Admiral Ackbar, but his skin was blue and he had yellow hair (more like mane) on his head.

I searched about him everywhere, but couldn't find anything. Who is he?

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean [Vober Dand](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vober_Dand)? His hair isn't yellow, but he's the closest I could find to a blue-skinned alien with a mane working for the Resistance in *[Star Wars: The Force Awakens Visual Dictionary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1465438165)*. Here's a shot someone posted:

[image]

Comment: Vober served in the Resistance's ground logistics division. He mentioned that the one he is looking for was a leader. Promotion? :3

Comment: @Saphirel - Given that a lot of these characters don't have dialogue, the OP might have mistook a leader of the ground crew giving orders to other members of the crew for a commander giving orders to pilots.